# How to prevent Talend ESB including unwanted libraries in built .kar file?

Tags: talend

I have a series of routes built through Talend ESB 6.5.1.

Some of these routes use custom beans, and these beans use java libraries which are in the Talend Studio repository.

However, Talend seems to include all the libraries for all the beans in every route (in the route jar file lib folder), regardless of either a) if the bean in question is used, and b) if the library needed at all, because it can be imported in Karaf anyway.

Because of version incompatibilities with the libraries in the Karaf runtime environment, these routes don't work if the libraries are included.

Is there a way of preventing Talend from bundling these libraries with the route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a **dependencies** tab 3rd one(Designer,Code,Dependencies), while opening the route in the IDE. it will list the dependencies. There's an option to remove the unwanted dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @resatz! Any dependencies that the route itself requires, such as libraries in the cConfig components, appear in the "bundle classpath" list of the dependencies tab, but default unticked, Is that what you mean? However, as far as I can see, the dependencies for the beans do not appear in this list - they are just bundled into the lib folder of the route .jar file regardless. (I'll update the question to make this clearer.)